# Rails belongs_to same model in multiple attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2

There is a model called Student and has an attribute called `:studies_level`.

`studies_level` can have one of the following values: `['school_graduate', 'undergraduate', 'graduate', 'postgraduate', 'doctoral', 'postdoctoral']`

There is also another model called `University`

If `:studies_level` is postgraduate then Student must fill the following attributes `:undergraduate_university` and `:postgraduate_university` with a University_id

Is there any way to achieve this with Rails model relations (belongs_to, etc) ?

Comment: When you say "must fill", are you referring to validation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
belongs_to :undergraduate_university, class_name: :University
belongs_to :postgraduate_university, class_name: :University
validates  :undergraduate_university, presence: true, if: :studies_level=='postgrad'
validates  :postgraduate_university, presence: true, if: :studies_level=='postgrad'
validates_associated  :undergraduate_university
validates_associated  :postgraduate_university
```